# Comparing variances of two unbiased estimators

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, unbiased-estimator, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

This question is from a Ph.D Qualifying Exam for Mathematical Statistics. Main reference is [Casella & Berger's *Statistical Inference*](https://amzn.to/2Lubhsb).

> Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be unbiased estimators of a parameter $\theta$ for
>   which the statistic $T$ is sufficient. Is it true that
>   $\mathrm{Var}(\mathrm{E}(W_1|T))\le \mathrm{Var}(W_2)$?

---

**My attempt:** I guess it is false, so I'm trying to find a counterexample.

If $T$ is complete, then $E(W_1|T)$ becomes the UMVUE so the inequality always holds. Therefore, a counterexample must be found in the case when $T$ is incomplete.

First I tried with $X_1 ,...,X_n \sim N(\theta,\theta),\:\:W_1 = X_1,\:W_2 =T= \bar{X}$, but I failed. The same attempt with $N(\theta,\theta^2)$ also failed.

How should I figure out whether the statement is true or false?

Comment: @StubbornAtom It is not, because in Rao-Blackwell theorem it must be $W_1=W_2$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I'm afraid you're misunderstanding the theorem. See http://people.ku.edu/~t926s829/07-blackwell.pdf

Comment: Ok sorry I messed up the hypothesis in your question. Ignore please.

Comment: Just saw this question on Math.se (old post) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2041487/321264.

Comment: I believe the following ought to work: Consider a sample of size $2$ from a Cauchy distribution (of arbitrary location $\theta$) and compare the midrange to the median as estimators of $\theta.$

Comment: @whuber I posted the solution below. Could you check if the solution is correct?

Comment: Indeed, when $T$ is incomplete, there is no reason for $\mathbb{E}(W_1|T)$ to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from $N(\theta,\theta)$ family, where $\theta$ is either 1 or 2. Then one can check that $T=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ is sufficient but incomplete statistic for $\theta$.(Take $g(T)=Te^{-T}$.) Now let $W_1=T/n$. Then $W_1$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$, and so is the sample variance $S^2$. Now let $W_2= W_1+a(S^2-W_1)=W_1+aU$, then $\text{Cov}(U,W_1)=-\text{Var}(W_1)<0$, which is due to the independence of sample mean and variance in a normal family. Also, note that $E(W_1|T)=W_1$ since $W_1$ is a function of $T$.

Then $\text{Var}(W_2)=\text{Var}(W_1)+2a\text{Cov}(U,W_1)+a^2\text{Var}(U)<\text{Var}(W_1)=\text{Var}(E(W_1|T))$ if $0<a<\dfrac{-2\text{Var}(W_1)}{\text{Var}(U)}$, so we successfully constructed a counterexample.